# Device to change which computer the input/output devices are connected to

Tags: laptop, display, keyboard, mouse, desktop

I have a laptop and a desktop computer at home. I want to be able to switch easily between using my laptop and using my desktop with the same mouse/monitor/keyboard without having to plug/unplug anything from my desktop each time i switch devices.

I suppose there is a device that lets you plugin a keyboard, mouse and monitor and connect that device to both the laptop and desktop. The device then decides which computer will be connected to the mouse/keyboard/monitor. For instance pressing a button on the device to switch between laptop and desktop. ([an image that illustrates what I mean](http://s7.postimg.org/x6zw9uaob/devices.png), I don't have enough reputation to post it directly yet).

I assume such a device or something similar exists but I can't find how its called and where I can buy it.

Comment: You mean a [KVM Switch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch)?  [Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Kvm-switch-diagram.svg/220px-Kvm-switch-diagram.svg.png) is a better image.  Pick your favorite computer parts store they all have one for sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [KVM switch](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=kvm%20switch), and the range is big. What you need is one of the cheaper ones, which basically lets you connect VGA and/or DVI in addition to some USB devices and sometimes including sound. This shouldn't set you back too much, as it's a fairly basic device. In large environments, it is common for entire [KVM systems](http://www.raritan.com/products/kvm-switches) that costs >10k USD, as these can run over ethernet instead of dedicated KVM cables, and often supports a massive amount of computers.

Alternatively, you can use [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) or one of its equivalents for a software approach. It allows you to set up a server (the one with the actual mouse and keyboard) and a client that lets itself be controlled by said mouse and keyboard if the correct hotkey is pressed.

**EDIT:**
It seems that Synergy is not free anymore, but I remember it as being good, and the price is fairly cheap. It does, however, have [many free alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/synergy/).

Comment: Thanks, the KVM switch is what I was looking for. Synergy (and similar products) sounds cool too, but the drawback is that I will still need to work with a small laptop display rather than having the laptop system displayed on the bigger desktop monitor.